# Condicional CSS first:child pero con Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Si tengo esta lista de elementos, y quiero ocultar únicamente el primero, con CSS sería así:

```css
li{
background: yellow;
border: 1px solid;
margin: 10px;
display: block;
}

li:first-child {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<li><a href="#">PRIMERO</a></li>
<li><a href="#">SEGUNDO</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TERCERO</a></li>
```

El problema se da cuando la lista es dinámica: podrían ser 0, 1, 2 o más elementos, en mi front no tengo cómo contarlos.

```css
li{
background: yellow;
border: 1px solid;
margin: 10px;
display: block;
}

li:first-child {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<li><a href="#">UNICO</a></li>
```

Cómo logro con javascript crear una condicional CSS? Que solo aplique first:child si hay más de 1 elemento, sino el display sería block.

Comment: Mejor pon el javascript que usas para crear esa lista dinámica, pues lo que se me ocurre es comprobar si esa lista tiene elementos antes de agregar el primero, y si no tiene le pongo un `<li></li>` antes del primero que voy a agregar, y así son dos, y en cambio, si ya tiene, le quito el primero si esta vacio, pues será que lo puse yo antes... no se si me explico. Así no cambio nada del CSS.

Comment: Gracias amigo, no se crean las listas desde JS, es un back que desconozco, no tengo acceso. Sólo puedo trabajar con el front y no tengo cómo saber la cantidad de elementos que el back me va a traer. muchas gracias por su comentario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías solucionarlo de la manera que el compañero @masterguru comenta. Desde **Javascript** comprobar si el listado a imprimir tiene más de un elemento y en caso de tenerlo, agregar una clase al primero para ocultarlo.

Pero si quisieras solucionarlo solamente a través de **CSS** podemos aprovecharnos de la "cascada" de **CSS** y de las pseudo-clases `first-child` y `only-of-type`.

Lo que he hecho ha sido primeramente ocultar los `<li>` que sean el primer hijo, tal y como lo tenías en tu código, para seguidamente mostrar los `<li>` que además no tengan ningún otro hermano que sea un `<li>`.

De esta manera se ocultaría el primer `<li>` solamente cuando tiene otros hermanos `<li>`, si se encuentra solo pues no se ocultaría.

```css
li {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
}

li:first-child {
  display: none;
}

li:only-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>Listado con 3 elementos, queremos que se oculte el primero</p>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">PRIMERO</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">SEGUNDO</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">TERCERO</a></li>
</ul>

<p>Listado con 1 elemento, no queremos que se oculte el primero</p>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">PRIMERO</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Referencias:** [cascada y herencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance), [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child), [:only-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:only-of-type)